# NHibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.Int32, got System.Int64

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Am using the following query to get a Client. The Client has a public Id of type long.

```
var client = Session.CreateQuery("from Client as c where c.Id = :Id").SetParameter("Id", 1, NHibernateUtil.Int64).UniqueResult<Client>();
```

Am getting the error:

> NHibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.Int32, got System.Int64

At the same time, the following works just fine.

```
var client = Session.Get<Client>(1L); //Or
var client = Session.CreateCriteria<Client>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", 1L)).UniqueResult<Client>();
```

What am i missing? Am using fluent nhibernate to create the mappings. I have tested the queries against a Sqlite and a MySql database. Same results.

**Edit1**: The schema generation from the mappings clearly is using bigint for the primary key on mysql. Thats why i am unable to understand what is expecting a Int32?

**Edit2**: okay, my Client class has a reference to a Report object. Its actually a one-to-one relationship in the db with the report table having a column clientID. The Report class had an id of type int. Once i changed its type to long, the error went away.

My mappings are as follows:

ClientMap:

```
HasOne<Report>(x => x.Report)
   .PropertyRef(x => x.Client)
   .LazyLoad()
   .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

ReportMap:

```
References(x => x.Client, "clientID").Unique();
```

**So, why did the problem solve itself by changing the type of the reportid from int to long. Secondly, why is it even bothering to fetch the report when i am not asking for it?**

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the issue with your custom bytecode provider was?  I seem to be having the same issue and have proven that it is my provider -- but there is not enough in the messages to lead me to an understanding as to why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-to-one keys need to have the same type definition since they use the same values. So a Client with ID = Int32.MaxValue + 1 would have a corresponding Report with ID = Int32.MaxValue + 1 so they have to be both `long`.

I recommend these articles to understand one-to-one and how most of the time you don't really need it:

- http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/27/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/
- http://web.archive.org/web/20100331014510/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/18/legacy-db-and-one-to-one-relations.aspx?